# How to create alias / synonym links to existing posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, redirect

I have a directory type website, where each post is a word definition. I want to set up synonyms of these words for audiences from different geographies.

For example, let’s say I have a post for “coriander” and I wanted this to appear in the post archives in search results for both “coriander” and “cilantro” so that American visitors would find it under the word they’re looking for.

The post content would ideally be the same, i.e. the “cilantro” link redirects to the “coriander”.

The beat way I can think to do this would be to have a separate post-type for synonyms, relate that to the original post with a custom field and then display ‘post’ and ‘synonym’ post types in all WP queries.

Is there a better or more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a redirect plugin and set up a bunch using the import feature. that might take a little while then you still have the problem with wanting to add the links to your page.
You can create a custom plugin that set's it all up, but I am not familiar off hand with a plugin that already exists.